# Destroyed sheets and towels in a turkish hotel

Tags: hotels, turkey

Me and a friend had too much to drink one night in turkey and he ended up making a sheet and towel unusable.

The hotel now wants compensation for these and I wonder how much they will charge us. The manager will not be back for several days and he will decide the cost of these.

How much does turkish hotels charge for new sheets and new towels?

Clothes are very cheap here so I can't imagine that it will be too expensive. The hotel is a mid-range one with excellent service (yet no porters).

Comment: Don't you think it will just be guesswork on our part?

Comment: Better hope the hotel doesn’t use 1000 thread count cotton sheets.

Comment: It is "Turkey" ;)

Comment: @HankyPanky well, maybe someone has experienced this before.

Comment: Even if someone has experienced that before, what guarantees that one hotel will use the same policy and charge as the one you used? I mean if I were to guess I would say the charge won’t be too much but that doesn’t help you.